# Is shifting an Ascii value by a random number between 3 and 7 digits even possible?

Tags: java

I am curious if it's even possible due to Ascii characters only having 3 digit integer codes. A random number between 3 and 7 digits just sounds outrageously large. Please let me know if I'm thinking about this all wrong.

- You must first take in the person’s first name.
- Then, you must take in the person’s last name.
- Then, you must convert the first and last letter of the person’s first name and last name into their ASCII values.
- Then, you must shift their ASCII value over by a random number between 3 and 7 digits.
- If your number goes past z, then, you must wrap around to a.  You cannot use if statements

Comment: The last point in the requirements answers your question.

Comment: Badly worded. Ignore the word "digits". Shift "by a random number between 3 and 7", "wrap around to a" "If your number goes past z".

Comment: @Andreas I was thinking that was what the actual intention was. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: Pay attention to the instructiuons - you aren't going to shift by a huge amount. "If your number goes past z, then, you must wrap around "

Comment: @Andreas If the requirements are stated that way, you can't just ignore it. But maybe the teacher made a mistake indeed.

Comment: If teacher truly meant "3 and 7 *digits*", i.e. a *random* number between `100` and `9999999`, the result would be so randomized that you might as well skip the shifting and just choose a random number between `0` and `25` (inclusive) and map that to `a` to `z`. **Makes no sense.**

Comment: It must be a mistake. Even shifting the lowest alphabetical Ascii value(65) by the lowest possible generated value(100) would still only leave 7 alphabetical letters as possible shift values. Just doesn't make sense to bother with that extremely low probability.  99.9% of the values would have to be wrapped

Answer (score 0):

The requirements don't say that the shifted value will fall into the ASCII range. Actually, the behaviour for the overflow is explicitly stated in the last point.

I think your teacher is trying to make you use the modulus operator. I won't give you a full solution but you should look into this direction.